# SharePoint Reporting Services - NLB issue

Tags: reporting-services, network, nlb

I have a problem which I suspect is due to incorrectly configured NLBs.

Scneario:
2 Web front end servers: SERVER01, SERVER02

SQL Reporting Services (SharePoint Integrated Mode) is installed ON SERVER01 only.

Intermittently, users get Reporting services exceptions when browsing reports using the DNS Name for Example:

> http://myintranet.mycompany.com/Reports/Report1.whatever

I narrowed down the problem by manually browsing to the Reports on each server like so:

> `http://SERVER01/Reports/Report1.whatever`  (works fine)
>
> `http://SERVER02/Reports/Report1.whatever`  (get page cannot be displayed)

So I understand that the issue occurs because Reporting Services is not installed on Server2, but this doesn't sound like correct behaviour. I'm not supposed to have Reporting services installed on both servers am I? Not according to MS documentation. They state you can even run in on a Application server (No web front end services) for scalability.

Anybody seen this behaviour before?
By the way, we are using CISCO ACE For load balancing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install Reporting Services Shared Addin in the SERVER 2 [your second WFE]. Kindly refer to the scale out architecture mentioned in technet.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479775.aspx

The presentation layer of SSRS reports on SharePoint Integrated mode depends on this component which adds specific capabilities on Web Servers to serve you the reports on your browser.

As mentioned in the technet documentation steps :-

> (1) Multiple web front-end (WFE) servers. The WFE servers require the Reporting Services add-in for SharePoint 2010. The following steps add a second application server to this tier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of this. You're a life saver!