# SSRS Intermittant Exceptions

Tags: reporting-services, kerberos, load-balancing, nlb

Someone assisted me this morning with one issue related to Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated mode: 
[SharePoint Reporting Services - NLB issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76255/sharepoint-reporting-services-nlb-issue/76256#76256)

Now I seem to have another issue.

The post above describes the environment. Basically, I have a 2 web front end server farm with some other application and search servers.

The way the environment is configured is:

SERVER1 WFE AND SQL REPORTING SERVICES

SERVER2 WFE ONLY

We use Network Load balancing  between these two servers. Sometimes, when browsing to reports the reports fail and we get a error on the ULS Logs for SERVER2 as follow:

`System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.`

Also, when browsing directly to the repots on SERVER1 (without using the DNS Load balancer URL), everything works fine. Browsing directly to the reports on SERVER2 gives the above error message.

I suspect a issue with Kerberos since Browsing directly to SERVER1 causes only 1 Hop where SERVER2 will cause a duoble hop.

This might also be a issue with NLB (We use a Cisco Hardware load balancer)

Any ideas on how I can identify and troubleshoot the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do the datasource of the report have integrated windows authentication selected ?

Comment: Yes they do. I suspect the reason why it's working is because SERVER1 is only 1 hop where SERVER2 is 2 hops.. The Web applications ARE NOT configured with Kerberos

Comment: And your datasource I'm assuming is a remote database outside the farm's topology where the user has some rights on the db directly ?

Comment: Actually, the datasource is a WCF Web service which reads data from SharePoint using the Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to find and fix the problem. Everything was Kerberos related. I changed my web application to use Kerberos and then everything was working fine.